# How accurate is the current read by /svh_controller/channel_currents?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, grasping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I´m working with a real SVH 5-Finger hand from Schunk and I have performed a lot of tests regarding to the current. As it was pointed out before, there is no force feedback on the hand so the current is the only relevant variable to measure how much "effort" is applied to an object.

I´m working on developing a grasp controller based on the current of the hand, therefore I´m using the topic /svh_controller/channel_currents provided by the driver. My question is wether this topic is reliable enough and if it contains an accurate measurement of the current consumption. Or in other words, should I use another method to obtain the current?

Best regards,

Charlie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302461/how-accurate-is-the-current-read-by-/svh_controller/channel_currents?/) by [CharlieMAC](https://answers.ros.org/users/32694/charliemac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Charlie,

there is an error of about +- 10 mA.

We compared the current reading of the topic to the actual current between the handcontrolcircuit and single motors to get this value.

---

Originally posted by [T.Meurer](https://answers.ros.org/users/37409/t.meurer/) with karma: 26 on 2018-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1